# Sorting time column derived from values of other columns using hybrid_property

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I'm trying to build an event-booking system as a side project to learn python and web development. Below are two of the models implemented in my project. An **EventSlot** represents a timeslot scheduled for a particular **Event**.

**Models**

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from dateutil.parser import parse
from datetime import timedelta
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property


class Event(db.Model):
    event_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String, index=True, nullable=False)
    duration = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)

    slots = db.relationship('EventSlot', cascade='all, delete', back_populates='event')


class EventSlot(db.Model):
    slot_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    event_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    event_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('event.event_id'))

    event = db.relationship('Event', back_populates='slots')
```

I've provided an admin page (Flask-Admin) for admin-users to view database records. On the EventSlot page, I included 'Start Time' and 'End Time' column which I want to make sortable. I've appended to the EventSlot model the following:

```
class EventSlot(db.Model):
    #...

    ## working as intended ##
    @hybrid_property
    def start_time(self):
        dt = parse(str(self.event_date))
        return dt.time().strftime('%I:%M %p')

    @start_time.expression
    def start_time(cls):
        return db.func.time(cls.event_date)


    ## DOES NOT WORK: can display derived time, but sorting is incorrect ##
    @hybrid_property
    def end_time(self):
        rec = Event.query.filter(Event.event_id == self.event_id).first()
        duration = rec.duration * 60
        derived_time = self.event_date + timedelta(minutes=duration)
        dt = parse(str(derived_time))
        return dt.time().strftime('%I:%M %p')

    @end_time.expression
    def end_time(cls):
        rec = Event.query.filter(Event.event_id == cls.event_id).first()
        duration = '+' + str(int(rec.duration * 60)) + ' minutes'
        return db.func.time(cls.event_date, duration)
```

As can be seen from the image below, the sort order is wrong when I sort by 'end time'. It appears to be still sorting by start time. What might be the problem here?

(Admittedly, I still don't understand hybrid_properties. I thought I had got it when got start_time working, but now it seems I still don't understand a thing...)

[image: sorting results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the expression for `end_time` the `cls.event_id` represents a column, not a value, so the query ends up performing an implicit join between `Event` and `EventSlot` and picks the first result of that join. This of course is not what you want, but instead for an `EventSlot` you want to find out the duration of the related `Event` in SQL. This seems like a good place to use a correlated scalar subquery:

```
@end_time.expression
def end_time(cls):
    # Get the duration of the related Event
    ev_duration = Event.query.\
        with_entities(Event.duration * 60).\
        filter(Event.event_id == cls.event_id).\
        as_scalar()
    # This will form a string concatenation SQL expression, binding the strings as
    # parameters to the query.
    duration = '+' + ev_duration.cast(db.String) + ' minutes'
    return db.func.time(cls.event_date, duration)
```

Note that the query *is not run* when the attribute is accessed in query context, but becomes a part of the parent query.